# Insert a splitter (or expander) inside a gridview

Tags: c#, datagrid, silverlight-4.0, expander, splitter

I'm using Silverlight 4's gridview in my page, and I would like to have collapsible columns (to hide some rarely needed information).  I had a look to `DataGridTemplateColumn` but it doesn't seem to allow me to do that.  Googleing on this problem didn't help me either. (the only information I found is to set the visibility and/or the width of the columns in the code, but thatdoesn't solve my problem of inserting the splitter/expander).

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haver you had a look at the [silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) yet? They have a nice expander in the [online demo](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) that may do what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes Brad, I'm using the toolkit, and this is what I want to use, an expander inside a gridview.  But I don't find a way to insert the expander.

Comment: Instead of adjusting the column, adjust the content within the column. Make the column's width auto-expand and place the Expander control within. When it's extended, so does the column. When collapsed, it's out of view.

Comment: That could be a solution, but how do I place the expander on the whole column ? If I use `DataGridTemplateColumn`, an expander will be present in  every cell, which is certainly not what I want.  I'd like to be able to apply this expander on the whole column at once. (but maybe it is not possible with this implementation).

Comment: @Shimrod You can use the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columnheaderstyle(v=VS.95).aspx to push the Expander to just the header of the column; then mimic the behavior of collapsing the column when Expanded/Collapsed.

Comment: @Aaron> I just tried it, but it seems that the click event doesn't hit the expander (no expander/collapsed event generated), and this solution won't allow me to make groups of collapsible columns (1 expander for x columns).

Comment: @Shimrod You will have to write custom code/logic to deal with wrapping the column header and column visually when the expander is clicked...